# c# convert string to int in expression

Tags: c#, string, integer, expression

I'm working on a small project that transforms a list of functions into c# code. 
For example: temp1.greaterThan(1); temp2.contains("a");
temp1, temp2 are expression variables in string type.
The source code is:

```
var temp1 = Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "temp1");
```

So I think I need to convert temp1 into an integer variable.
I've tried following ways but none worked:

```
Expression greaterThan = Expression.GreaterThan(temp1, Expression.Constant(1));
```

It will throw exeption because temp1 is string and hence cannot compare with 1.

```
Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(typeof(int).GetMethod("Parse"), temp1), Expression.Constant(1));
```

It throws "Ambiguous match found." exception

```
Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToInt32"), temp1), Expression.Constant(1));
```

Same exception: Ambiguous match found.

```
Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Convert(temp1,typeof(Int32)), Expression.Constant(1));
```

Exception: No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Int32'.

So I'm thinking i would need to have a convert method inside the Expression.GreaterThan method.
Anyone has an idea?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `int.Parse` to parse a string instead of explicit conversion. Note that `int.Parse` has a few overloads, that's why you get an "Ambiguous match found" exception.

```
var temp1 = Expression.Variable(typeof(string), "temp1");

//use int.Parse(string) here
var parseMethod = typeof(int).GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(string) }); 

var gt = Expression.GreaterThan(Expression.Call(parseMethod, temp1), Expression.Constant(1));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I'm looking for.